# jQuery toggle not working with next() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

In the following example all the 3 divs with class ".container2" are hidden by default. When I click an h2, the div next to it shall open (which is happening) but when I click the h2 again, the div is not closing but remains open. Please, help me out why it is not getting toggled?

**Example:**

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
  * {margin:0px;padding:0px;}
  h2{background:#000;color:#fff;margin:10px;border-radius:4px;padding:5px 10px;}
  .container2{background:yellow;color:#000;margin:0px 10px;padding:2px 10px;}
</style>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container2').hide();

    $('h2').click(function(){
      $('.container2').hide();
      $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Set-I</h2>
<div class="container2">123</div>

<h2>Set-II</h2>
<div class="container2">456</div>

<h2>Set-III</h2>
<div class="container2">789</div>

</body>

</html>
```

> **NOTE:** At a time I only want maximum 1 div to open. If I remove
>   `$('.container2').hide()` then more than 1 divs might open at a time,
>   which I don't want!

Comment: `$('.container2').hide();` removet this line from the click block.

Comment: But, then more than 1 divs might open at a time clicking multiple h2 elements, which I don't want.

Comment: I just posted one answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide all but the current toggled one

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
  * {margin:0px;padding:0px;}
  h2{background:#000;color:#fff;margin:10px;border-radius:4px;padding:5px 10px;}
  .container2{background:yellow;color:#000;margin:0px 10px;padding:2px 10px;}
</style>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container2').hide();

    $('h2').click(function(){
      var container2 = $(this).next();
      $('.container2').not(container2).hide();
      container2.toggle();
  });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Set-I</h2>
<div class="container2">123</div>

<h2>Set-II</h2>
<div class="container2">456</div>

<h2>Set-III</h2>
<div class="container2">789</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is this line:

```
$('.container2:visible').not($(this).next()).hide();
```

This change will do the intended behavior.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
    h2 {
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 10px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    
    .container2 {
      background: yellow;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0px 10px;
      padding: 2px 10px;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.container2').hide();

      $('h2').click(function() {
        $('.container2:visible').not($(this).next()).hide();
        $(this).next().toggle();
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <h2>Set-I</h2>
  <div class="container2">123</div>

  <h2>Set-II</h2>
  <div class="container2">456</div>

  <h2>Set-III</h2>
  <div class="container2">789</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do that in two steps.

step 1: hide all `h2` divs.

step 2: only toggle the current `next() h2` div.

and you should do it with a callback function passed to `.hide()` to guarantee that it will only be executed after the function has finished hiding the other divs.

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
  * {margin:0px;padding:0px;}
  h2{background:#000;color:#fff;margin:10px;border-radius:4px;padding:5px 10px;}
  .container2{background:yellow;color:#000;margin:0px 10px;padding:2px 10px;}
</style>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container2').hide();

    $('h2').click(function(){
      
      var btn = $(this).next();
      $('.container2').hide(function(){
          btn.toggle();
      });
      
  });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Set-I</h2>
<div class="container2">123</div>

<h2>Set-II</h2>
<div class="container2">456</div>

<h2>Set-III</h2>
<div class="container2">789</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but, then more than 1 divs can be opened at a time, which I don't want.

Comment: @Deadpool I have updated my answer to accommodate your requrest